# Redmine + Gitolite Raspberry

Tags: nginx, ssh, redmine, gitolite, raspbian

I have been at this for days now. I think I am simply too stupid. Please help.

I have redmine + gitolite 2.3-1 setup on nginx 1.2.1-2.2+wheezy1 (please find more details under (2) Both services are running on the same machine. The rake commands where run with user and group redmine. nginx however is running as www-data user. User

```
git@raspberrypi:/usr/share/redmine$ id redmine
uid=110(redmine) gid=113(redmine) groups=113(redmine),33(www-data),112(git)
```

My raspberry is behind a NAT, ports are forwarded correctly, ssh access works to user git, who is also running gitolite.

The repo that I want to use for my project was setup with redmine, which worked fine. Now redmine tells me ssh, http and https links to the repo to use for cloning and pushing etc.

```
Clone Repository :

git clone ssh://git@<myURL>.org/<myProjectName>-gitolite.git
```

Now when I try cloning the repo I get the famous message:

```
$ git clone git@<myURL>.org:<myProjectName>-gitolite.git
Cloning into '<myProjectName>-gitolite'...
fatal: '<myProjectName>-gitolite.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I have cloned the repo locally, there it shows that redmine has inserted the deployment keys just fine:

```
repo    <myProjectName>-gitolite
RW+     =       redmine__deploy_key__1385587228_1212 redmine__deploy_key_...
```

I am really lost here, please help. I give you more information if needed, because, as you can see from the long text I don't understand the setup too well as well. It is too complicated, I think.

Redmine tells me also that I could use http and https checkouts, but a netstat reveals that there is no server listening on 443.

I am exhausted now, please help.

(2) I have the following system:

Linux raspberrypi 3.6.11-rpi-aufs ... armv6l GNU/Linux
Redmine: svn checkout URL: http://redmine.rubyforge.org/svn/branches/2.3-stable
plugins: plugins/redmine_git_hosting/
         plugins/redmine_plugin_views_revisions/
I am using nginx to access redmine, currently via http.

```
git@raspberrypi:/usr/share/redmine$ ps aux |grep nginx
root      2796  0.0  0.1  11544   828 ?        Ss   Nov27   0:00 nginx: master process      /usr/sbin/nginx
www-data  2798  0.0  0.3  12016  1448 ?        S    Nov27   0:03 nginx: worker process
www-data  2799  0.0  0.2  11704  1152 ?        S    Nov27   0:03 nginx: worker process
www-data  2800  0.0  0.3  12028  1768 ?        S    Nov27   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data  2801  0.0  0.2  12028  1392 ?        S    Nov27   0:03 nginx: worker process
```

Comment: I should also mention that cloning the repo bypassing gitolite works just fine, but then I have the problem that I am not able to push to the repository. So git clone git@<myURL>.org:~/repositories/<myProjectName>-gitolite.git works.